# Change format of ticklabels

Tags: c#, excel

I want to change the format of the x-axes label.
I try the following code but nothing changed on my diagram. The number is still showing like this `0,034` but I want to have this `3,4%` on my x-axes.

This code doesn't work:

```
    Axis axe = (Axis)chartQuote.Chart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);           
    axe.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0,00%";
```

Comment: You might want to check out [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). It makes manipulation of Excel files using C# way easier.